# Is it possible to setup an IBM MQ reciever channel to recieve messages from two different queue managers

Tags: ibm-mq

Is it possible to setup an IBM MQ receiver channel to receive messages from two different queue managers with the sender channels named identically. I am looking at a situation where a client wishes to have two queue managers (A and B) able to send messages to the same destination queue manager (C). A and B are setup up in an active / passive cluster setup without shared storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not only possible to set up IBM MQ Receiver channels to receive messages from two different queue managers, it is recommended to do so.

For example, on QM3 (the receiving queue manager) make the following definition:

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(TO.QM3) CHLTYPE(RCVR) TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

Then on both QM1 and QM2 make the following definitions:

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(TO.QM3) CHLTYPE(SDR) TRPTYPE(TCP) CONNAME('qm3-host-name(qm3-port)') XMITQ(QM3)
DEFINE QLOCAL(QM3) USAGE(XMITQ)
```

Doing this will NOT cause sequence number issues as the state for each running receiver channel instance is keyed off the channel name plus the partner queue manager name, so there will be state for:-

- Channel:TO.QM3 from Partner QMgr QM1
- Channel:TO.QM3 from Partner QMgr QM2

Both channel instances can be running at the same time quite happily without interfering with each other.

You can see this state by issuing the following command on the receiving queue manager, QM3:-

```
DISPLAY CHSTATUS(TO.QM3)
```

Comment: Is this configuration noted in the KC anywhere? Does the uniqueness come only from the SDR qmgr name? For example if there was one SDR that could point to the same RCVR channel name on two different QMs with different QM names (for instance the DNS name or IP is behind a load balancer) would  it cause seq num issues?

Comment: @JoshMc - Pointing one SDR to a RCVR on two different QMs (i.e. through loading balancing IP) is not a supported setup. If the channel ends in-doubt, it must connect to the same queue manager as previous to resolve the in-doubt batch. This is why it is not supported to put an F5 in between SDR-RCVR channels. But that is not the topic the OP was asking about.

Comment: Morag, thank you for the additional information and confirmation that the reverse of what you described would not work. In the past we had tried a similar "reverse" setup only the destination RCVR channel was on two queue manager instances with the same name, I was hoping maybe based on what you described that if the RCVR QMs had different names that uniqueness could come from the RCVR QM name as well. Do you know if the KC shows examples of the multiple SDR to single RCVR setup, this is one I would like to read more about that could be useful in the future. Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: @JoshMc - This link (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q015540_.htm) mentions generic receivers.

Comment: @JoshMc - and of course, the whole of MQ clustering is based on this model.

Comment: @JoshMc - in fact many of the channel definition examples in KC use the TO.ME model.